# WCF REST Service goes to sleep after inactivity

Tags: wcf, iis, rest

I've got a WCF REST service that is declared in a regular ASP.NET web project:

```
[ServiceContract]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public class BasicApp
```

I'm using it as a service layer for an iPhone app I'm building, so I'm requesting it using the excellent ASIHTTPRequest library.

The service itself is working just fine, but when it has been idle for approximately 10 minutes the service seems to go to sleep, which in the end gives me timeout issues on the iPhone.

If I request the service through the browser it's the same, but after 30 seconds or so the service "wakes up" and then all consecutive requests are really fast. I know I can up the timeout limit on the iPhone, but that doesn't really seem to work very well for a handheld device.

I'm guessing it's a configuration issue. The service is hosted on Win2008R2 with IIS 7.5

The IIS website is configured with it's own AppPool running .NET framework v4 with Integrated Pipeline.

Anyone has an idea how to resolve this?

Comment: The most probable cause of this could be App Pool recycle in IIS. Check the AppPool recycle setting for IIS http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/applicationPools/add/recycling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application pool hosting your service defines Idle Time-out property (advanced settings of app pool in IIS management console) which defaults to 20 minutes. If no request is received by the app pool within idle timeout the worker processes serving the pool is terminated. After receiving a new request the IIS must start the process again, the process must load application domain and all related assemblies, compile .svc file, run the service host and process the request.

The solution can be increasing idle time-out but the meaning of this time-out is correct handling of server resources. If the process is not needed it should be stopped. Another ugly workaround is using some ping process (for example cron job or scheduled task on the server) which will regularly ping call some method on the service or page in the same application.

Edit: This answer is obsolete - it was written for old IIS versions where "AlwaysRunning" option wasn't available. Please check other answers.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was afraid this was the answer :)
For now I'll ping the service to keep it alive.

Comment: "The solution can be increasing idle time-out but the meaning of this time-out is correct handling of server resources. If the process is not needed it should be stopped." I just cant accept that. what if it takes 10 minutes to load my service? what if I have legal obligations for performance? What about cached data? The ugly thing is not workaround, its the approach that the programmer\sysadmin doesn't know whats the best solution for his specific scenario.

Answer (score 20):

No need to ping your server, here is a screenshot of the setting under advanced settings for the application pool. Change Start Mode to AlwaysRunning and it will stop sleeping.

[image: Change Start Mode to AlwaysRunning]

Comment: This is only relevant to IIS 8.0 as IIS 7.5 does not have it

Comment: actually, it is available in 7.5, just hidden in the applicationHost.config.

Answer (score 7):

This tells you how to set autostart, its in the applicationHost.config settings for your appPool

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677260.aspx

added for completeness
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config

```
<applicationPools>
    <add name=”MyAppPool” startMode=”AlwaysRunning” />
</applicationPools>
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using IIS 7.5 you can turn on application auto-start on your webapp, this will ensure that the service stays "alive".

--larsw

Answer (score 0):

Here is a compromise beetween creating self-hosted WCF windows service and disabling AppPool idle timeaout and recycling properties and Pinging service each minute.

There are 2 events. 
5074 - [IIS Application Pool Recycling](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc735298(v=ws.10).aspx)
5186 - [IIS Application Pool Recycling](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc735034(v=ws.10).aspx)

It is possible to attach event handler (run PowerShell script) for these types of events. Described here: [Trigger a PowerShell Script from a Windows Event](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wincat/2011/08/25/trigger-a-powershell-script-from-a-windows-event/)

PowerShell script:

```
param($eventRecordID,$eventChannel)

Start-Sleep -s 1

$query2 = @"
    <QueryList><Query Id='0' Path='$eventChannel'><Select Path='$eventChannel'>*[System[(EventRecordID=$eventRecordID)]]</Select></Query></QueryList>
"@

$Events = Get-WinEvent -FilterXml $query2
if($Events.Count -gt 0)
{
    $evt1 = [xml]$Events[0].toXML()

    $appPool  = $evt1.event.EventData.Data | where { $_.Name -eq 'AppPoolID' }
    if($appPool)
    {
        $appPoolID = $appPool.'#text'

        switch($appPoolID)
        {
            "AppPool" { Invoke-WebRequest -Method Head -Uri http://localhost:8080 }
            default {}
        }
    }
}
```

So, each time your IIS hosted service is going to "sleep", you gently wake it up.

Answer (score -1):

artfulhacker got it correct. Switching the startMode to AlwaysRunning allowed the web service to always be live. We are using IIS with AAR/ Server Farms for load balancing. 
Here is a screen shot of the startMode setting in IIS6/ WinServer 2003.
[image: IIS6 startMode]