# How to stop a WCF service on IIS from becoming idle

Tags: c#, iis

.NET 4.0/IIS 7

What is the best way to ensure that a WCF is always available on IIS?  Currently if a service is not used it goes to sleep and takes approximately 10 seconds to wake up.

Should I change the idle time-out from the default of 20 to 0?  Also, would the new auto-start feature be of good use for this?  Is there anything else that I could use?

Thanks,

Richard.

Comment: Have a windows service calling a dummy aspx page/service every few minutes?

Comment: Thanks Holystream.  We have that right now to 'wake-up' the service but I'm figuring there must be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801497/wcf-rest-service-goes-to-sleep-after-inactivity). And, yes, autostart in IIS 7.5 can be used to keep the service awake.