# WCF proxy close basicHttpBinding - Help explain behavior

Tags: .net, wcf, proxy, basichttpbinding

I have the following code on WCF Service and I am using **basicHttpBinding**

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            // Sleep for a minute
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000);
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }
}
```

I have the following code on client and the client has a "sendTimeout" of only 1 second (I want the client to timeout before the server responds)

```
Service1Client clientProxy = new Service1Client();
        try
        {

            Console.WriteLine(clientProxy.GetData(10));
            clientProxy.Close();
        }            
        catch (TimeoutException)
        {
            if (((ICommunicationObject)clientProxy).State == CommunicationState.Opened)
            {
                // In the case of TimeoutException the state is not faulted and 
                // "close" is invoked
                clientProxy.Close();
            }
        }
```

What I see in IIS log for the reqeust is:

> 2012-09-07 07:22:51 ::1 POST /SimpleTimeWCF/Service1.svc - 80 - ::1 -
>   200 0 **64** 60015

You can observe that the status is 200 and sc-win32-status is 64 and time-taken is 60015 (around a minute).
*While the WCF service is busy processing the requesting, client has invoked clientProxy.Close. What is expected behavior on the server?*

What is the expected behavior of "client proxy close" method invocation on the server when using basicHttpBinding? 

*Does the behavior change when using other bindings? Ex: Net TCP binding? When we use net tcp binding does invoking "close" on proxy on end the "tcp connection" established with the server?*

PS: Note that I have set Enable HTTP Keep-alive on IIS to false

Comment: Can you elaborate how this question is different from [your earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12278232/419956)?

Comment: Hello Jeroen, In the earlier question I was wondering whether receiving sc-win32-status of 64 was due to some underlying network issue and if anybody has encountered similar issues. I found out later that the WCF service is the culprit and I have updated that question to reflect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service will get the request from the client. It will process the request, taking 60 seconds. The client has "given up" in the mean time, but with HTTP it has no way of notifying the service that the previous request is not needed anymore.

In the end, the service:

- will finish up the way it should, giving [HTTP Status 200 "OK"](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)
- will not be able to respond to the client because it already timed out, ending in [code 64 "ERROR_NETNAME_DELETED"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382.aspx)

Comment: That is what I suspected too. What happens if the binding is net tcp? Does it behave differently? Updated the question as well

Comment: Ooh good question. I'm not sure what the IIS log would show for net.tcp endpoints. Setting up net.tcp in IIS is not entirely trivial, if I have time I may try it to check.

Comment: Not too surprising, but net.tcp requests don't show up in the default iis logs.