# IIS 7.5 throws sc-win32-status: 995 after 60 seconds on web service (ASMX) request

Tags: web-services, .net-4.0, web-config, iis-7.5, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a Web Application in .NET 4.0 Integrated mode calling a web service (ASMX) in .NET 2.0 Integrated mode on the same server via localhost.

9 out of 10 times all works fine, but occasionally the Web Application get's a "Request timed out" and "Thread was being aborted" error during the call. It gives the error on the last line of this code example:

```
 Dim Service As New localhost.Service
 Dim Input As New localhost.InputProduct
 Dim Ret As New localhost.OutputProduct 
 Try
     Ret = Service.RequestProduct(Input) 
 Catch 
 Finally
   Service.Dispose()    
   If Ret.succesfull = True Then
      If Response.IsClientConnected = True Then
         Response.Redirect("success.aspx", False)
      End If    
   End If 
End Try
```

In the log file of the web service I get a sc-win32-status: 995 and a sc-status: 200, typically the time-taken is always a little bit more than 60 seconds (time-take: 62743). Normally this would take 14 seconds to complete without errors.

The call is made in the code behind of the ASPX page after a button is clicked. 
On the page there is an Updatepanel and the button is used as a PostBackTrigger.

Question: Why do I get these "request timed out" error after the web service call?

Server:

- Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1
- IIS 7.5
- Microsoft UrlScan 3.1
- Windows Firewall

Comment: I added the question, to be more precise. I tried a lot of different settings in IIS, but nothing seems to work. I hope to get a clue about where I can find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer to this problem. It turned out to be this piece of code in the web.config:

```
<pages smartNavigation="true">
```

After turning this off I didn't receive any time-out errors anymore.
The reason for the time-out is probably the IFRAME that the smartNavigation setting generates in IE browsers (not in Firefox/Chrome)

I have used this setting in .NET 2.0 to [eliminating the flash caused by navigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.smartnavigation%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), after upgrading to .NET 4.0 Visual Studio didn't give any clue that this setting was deprecated.

I found the answer, because I had an other problem to deal with. After using the latest [ajaxToolkit](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/) for .NET 4.0 I had this javascript alert error in IE7/8 while using the AutoCompleteExtender:

> Stack overflow at line: 0

This turned out to be related to the smartNavigation setting. So removing this setting fixed two problems at once. Hopefully I help someone with this, because for me it was one of the most annoying error's I've found in the short history of internet.

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing httpRuntime executionTimeout = "xxx" tag located in the machine.config for your web server. The default may be two short for your situation. Value expressed in seconds consider doubling it.

Comment: Thanks, but I already changed that value in my web.config. The call takes around 15 sec. to complete. The request is successful in those 15 sec. only I get a time out afterwards with a sc-win32-status: 995 error.