# FileSystemWatcher Task in ASP.NET WCF Service Behaving Weird and Unreliably

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, filesystemwatcher

I followed [this tutorial](http://sudhanshumishradotnet.blogspot.com/2012/04/c-watching-appconfig-file-for-changes.html) to schedule a FileSystemWatcher task in my ASP.NET WCF service (running in an IIS server) to allow hot config changes. Here is my version of the implementation described in the tutorial...

```
// FileSystemWatcher declaration
private static FileSystemWatcher s_configWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher()
{
    Path = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath,
    NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite,
    Filter = "Web.config"
};

...
// inside non-static constructor of FileSystemWatcher's owner
s_configWatcher.Changed += OnConfigChange;
s_configWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
...

// this has been modified to debug the problem in question
static void OnConfigChange(object source, FileSystemEventArgs args)
{
    try
    {
        string oldValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[myKey];
        s_configWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
        string newValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[myKey];
        Tools.LogConfigChange(oldValue, newValue);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Tools.LogException(e);
    }
    finally
    {
        s_configWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }
}
```

Note that I'm not using a dedicated thread to instantiate the FileSystemWatcher as in the tutorial...I don't understand what that buys you.

So, the weirdness is that this FileSystemWatcher seems to miss config changes that occur during periods of inactivity.

My service has a `status-check` endpoint that I use to force activity...

```
public Stream StatusCheck()
{
    Tools.LogStatusCheck();
    return Tools.SerializeObject(new StatusCheckResponse { Success = true });
}
```

For completeness, here are my (Log4Net) logging functions...

```
public static void LogStatusCheck()
{
    log.Debug("Status check. Current value: " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[SessionManager.s_prodDbLimitKey]);
}

public static void LogConfigChange(string oldValue, string newValue)
{
    log.Debug("Old value: " + oldValue + Environment.NewLine + "New value: " + newValue);
}

public static void LogException(Exception e)
{
    log.Debug(e.ToString());
}
```

Given the following workflow...

```
Start service
Touch status-check endpoint
Change config value from 200 to 201
Touch status-check endpoint
Change config value from 201 to 202
Change config value from 202 to 203
Touch status-check endpoint
Change config value from 203 to 204
Touch status-check endpoint
Change config value from 204 to 205
Change config value from 205 to 206
Touch status-check endpoint
Change config value from 206 to 207
Stop service
```

Here is what I see in my logs...

```
10:04:44-05:00
Status check. Current value: 200


10:04:51-05:00
Old value: 200
New value: 200


10:04:54-05:00
Status check. Current value: 201


10:04:58-05:00
Old value: 201
New value: 201


10:05:05-05:00
Status check. Current value: 203


10:05:10-05:00
Old value: 203
New value: 203


10:05:12-05:00
Status check. Current value: 204


10:05:16-05:00
Old value: 204
New value: 204


10:05:22-05:00
Status check. Current value: 206


10:05:27-05:00
Old value: 206
New value: 206
```

Not only does the FileSystemWatcher *not* pick up config changes that occur between periods of activity, the old and new config values in the log are identical. When I look at things in the debugger, I see that the values are in fact different (what I would expect them to be), but they're still written out to log as identical values.

When I started to investigate this issue, I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16426248/858003) to a seemingly similar question, but changing the Start Mode of my application pool to AlwaysRunning seemed to have no effect on this problem whatsoever.

For the life of me I can't figure out what's going on. My boss and I looked at this problem together, and he seemed to be equally flummoxed. Am I doing something wrong in the way I'm configuring the FileSystemWatcher? Does anyone have any experience w/ scheduled tasks in ASP.NET WCF services? Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe ConfigurationManager is caching the file. Can you try to read the file without using it?

Comment: Isn't that what ````ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");```` is meant to address?

Comment: Yep, you are right. I missed those lines on the code. Worth to give it a go anyway :)