# MSMQ stop processing messages from queue

Tags: c#, wcf, msmq

I am using MSMQ in WCF services. I am facing one issue in MSMQ, MSMQ stops processing messages from a queue after some time of intervals. I have to make a request to WCF service(.svc file) to start MSMQ. After requesting svc file MSMQ start processing messages from the queue.

I don't know exactly when MSMQ stop processing but, it stops after some time. Do I want to know why MSMQ goes in idle state? How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I am speculating that you are hosting the WCF service in IIS. You can host the WCF service as a windows service, which will solve your problem. Otherwise have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801497/wcf-rest-service-goes-to-sleep-after-inactivity) for some IIS WCF service idle ideas.